# Configure multiple VLAN on a Broadcom NetXtreme 57XX adapter

Tags: windows-7, networking, vlan, broadcom

I'd like to use multiple VLAN on a Broadcom NetXtreme 57XX network adapter on Windows 7.

I'm used to do it on *BSD, but I can't find how to do it on Windows.
It's ok to set 1 VLAN on 1 adapter.

I tried to find a way to do it with the "Broadcom Advanced Control Suite 4" software without success.

Any help on how it works in Windows would be really great!